# How to get reference of map value?

Tags: c++, stl

Generally std::map::operator[] returns the reference to the object.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

```
std::map<char*, char*>* myMap1 = new std::map<char*, char*>() ;
char* c1 = new char[100];
strcpy(c1,"fggf");
char* c2 = new char[100];
strcpy(c2 ,"gdgfd");
myMap1->insert(std::pair<char*,char*>(c1,c2));
char* v1=  (*myMap1)[c1];
char** v2=  &(*myMap1)[c1];
```

In this program (*myMap1)[c1] is not returning reference, this syntax only  &(*myMap1)[c1] returning reference why?

Comment: How about use `std::map<std::string, std::string>` and drop all the pointers and `new`s?

Comment: If you use pointers as the key, it will be the *pointer* that is the key, not what it points to! For example, `(*myMap1)[c1]` and `(*myMap1)["fggf"]` will be two different entries in the map.

Comment: You might do `char*& v1=  (*myMap1)[c1];` to get reference, instead of dropping the reference.

Comment: Too many `new` here.

Comment: `std::map<char*, char*>` most likely is not what you want.  This will not compare the strings that are the keys but the address of them putting them in some implementation defined order.  You really should be using `std::map<std::string, std:string>` or `std::map<std::string_view, std::string_view>`

Comment: It seems you confound reference and pointer.

Answer (score 1):

**C++ and C are best not mixed!**
Don't use char* when you can use string (or string_view if you have C++17)

```
map<string, string> myMap; //C++ prefers value sementatics, don't go for pointers 
                            //unless absolutely necessary, and if it is...
auto myMapPtr = make_unique<map<string, string>>(); //Use smart pointers! 
myMap["fggf"] = "gdgfd"; //Lots of people don't know that [] also inserts, no need to construct a pair...

string c2 = MyMap.at("fggf"); //that's it!
```

That's it, all you need is three lines. Don't get confused. :)

Comment: Method `at()` throws — apparently, if OP had no idea about the correct C++, it will catch him off-guard. Also, he used pointer seemingly just because of his habits, so there's no need for a smart one. If you want to dodge construction of redundant `std::pair`, there are `emplace` variants, but try not to use `[]` to insert — it looks cryptic for starters, they perceive it differently.

Answer (score 1):

I support the answer above, but if you **insist** on using C, use this:

```
std::map<const char*, const char*>* myMap1 = new std::map<const char*, const char*>();
const char* c1 = "fggf";
const char* c2 = "gdgfd";
myMap1->insert(std::pair<const char*,const char*>(c1,c2));
const char* v1=  myMap1[c1];
const char** v2=  &(myMap1[c1]);
```